# Playwright-python при загрузке в heroku выдаёт ошибку, что делать?

Tags: python, flask, heroku, deploy

У меня есть небольшой сервер на flask и модуль, использующий модуль playwright. При загрузке на heroku, он просит установить playwright. Я пытался добавить в Procfile строку с установкой playwright, но это не дало результатов. Можете посоветовать, как правильно использовать playwright в heroku?

Comment: https://playwright.tech/blog/running-playwright-on-heroku

Comment: @GrAnd, я до этого использовал этот сборочный пакет, но именно сейчас каким-то чудом это сработало) спасибо

Comment: @GrAnd, но у меня появился другой вопрос. Я уже упоминал, что делаю маленький сервер на flask. В таком случае, если я загружаю всё в этом сборочном пакете, по какой ссылке я могу обратиться к своим crud методам?

Comment: @AnderZero на хероку в личком кабинете можно открыть приложение, там имеются все необходимые данные

Comment: @Ян Морозов, вы имеет ввиду url приложения? Его я нашел, но когда я пытаюсь обратиться к эндпоинтам мне выдаётся: "cannot GET"